# How to deploy the ASP.NET Pages to the server and run？

Tags: asp.net

i am new to asp, can you please tell me how to run an aspx page at server.

i have created a sample asp page in my machine,now i need run the .asp page in server. can you people tell me the steps to run. i mean what all the asp file needs to get copyed to server, do we need to make any changes to web.config file?,
which folder we need to keep in server to execute it. how do i achieve all these?..

i googled a bit, but it was not much helpful...

in server i have created a virtual directory, IIS is installed, rest i dont no.. how to do..
please let me know

Comment: are you not using visual studio ?

Comment: if yes press 'F5' and the magic will begin

Comment: yes, i do have VS 2008.. i know by pressing F5 magic begins.. it works in my system.. how about in server.. how do i keep files to run

Comment: so you wanna know how to deploy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question title should be "How to deploy a asp.net website" to get right answer. You can check following links for the same -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y1404zt(VS.80).aspx // Very easy walk-through tutorial
http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Deploy-ASP.NET.aspx // To understand all options of deployment

Comment: You're welcome. This is first time  my answer has been accepted as best answer.

Answer (score 3):

to deploy your application to a server.

You would have to have a server with IIS installed and ASP.NET enabled(and working).

You should take the folder in inetpub and copy it to your server and that's it.

If your project is name `foobar`, there should be a directory name foobar in `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\` copy that to your web root in the server and you are done.

Visual Studio provide some way to do it in the GUI, you can see the [article](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Deploy-ASP.NET.aspx) for more details

Answer (score 1):

You need to either use the default website on IIS or set up a new one. After that it can be as easy as just copying your site in the directory your website set up to.

You can configure IIS if you right click on the My Compute icon, and choose Manage, then find the web server towards the bottom.

Try to search MSDN for more, or codeproject.com or this site, and look for aspx IIS set up.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know how to install IIS by now - so you have to go to Run > inetmgr and hit Enter

The Internet Information Services console is opened - expand a couple of nodes till you see the default website. Right click the default website - click New - Virtual Directory...

Enter ther name by which you need to access it (as in http://servername/WebSitename/abc.aspx). Then enter the path to the executables (which is the path containing the bin directory of your compiled code) - finish the wizard and you are done.

Once you have learnt this process you dont have to deo it this painfully now. Use the publish feature of visual studio instead.

All the best

Answer (score 0):

u should check ASP option too when u install IIS in control panel. I had the same problem but now I can run .ASP by placing the file in wwwroot directory. IIS.>WWW Services>Application Development Features>ASP. It is better to check all options under ADF. Check it too > http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-iis-7/installing-iis-on-windows-vista-and-windows-7