# Opening .ASPX files?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I've been working on a website with database access in ASP.NET, VB.NET and SQL server for a University project. I've been able to build and test all my forms and they all work as they should so now has come the time to submit my work on a CD. I've been told that I have to explain to my Lecturer about how to open the files/project but I went to test that the default page opened (using Firefox), but unfortunately they won't open and I get the following error:

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: file:///C:/Users/NAME/Visual%20Studio%202010/WebSites/FOLDER/Default.aspx

Line Number 1, Column 2:<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="false"
-^
```

Is there any way that I can get the files to open from the CD (obviously after amending the file locations in the code) in a web browser? Would making a extremely simple HTML page with a hyperlink to the ASPX page work, or would it require "building"/"compiling"?

I've been using Microsoft's Visual Studio Web Developer 2010 Express to write and build my code and the pages then open in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Without installing IIS Express or putting the website into the users inetpub/wwwroot folder, you would not be able to open the files as they require a server to compile and run them.

Even then they would require the version of .net, which you used to develop the website, installed on their machine.

Checkout this question here for some more info
[How to deploy the ASP.NET Pages to the server and run？](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753733/how-to-run-aspx-page)

To get extra credit from Lecturer, look into deploying your website to a free hosting server. Maybe https://appharbor.com/ That way you can send the files, but also a link to the website in it's working state.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Fix for ‘XML Parsing Error: not well-formed Line Number 1, Column 2′ Error](http://mycodetrip.com/2007/03/26/fix-for-xml-parsing-error-not-well-formed-line-number-1-column-2-error_36/)